# Хранение списка групп объектов

Tags: mysql, база-данных, структуры

Говорят, что глупых вопросов не бывает, я так не считаю. Каждый вопрос дилетанта глуп в нескольких плоскостях одновременно. Вот, к примеру, пожалуйста, глупый вопрос от меня.

Имеется таблица с категориями товаров, вида:

id | name | quantity |
1  | butt    | 99         |

Раньше этого было вполне достаточно. Задача заключалась исключительно в отслеживании и корректировке остатков. Даже моей "спецподготовки" в области веб-разработки хватило чтобы за час сваять монумент моей криворукости и водрузить это все на линупс.

Теперь же появилась необходимость формировать паллеты с этими товарами.

Я вижу вот такое решение этой задачи:
Таблица с типами объектов:
id | name

Таблица с паллетами:
id | name

И таблица с товарами на паллетах:
id | type | pallete | quantity

Но меня беспокоит, что в интернетах консенсуса по поводу того как надо решать подобные задачи нет. Вот кто мне может подсказать насколько я ошибаюсь в подходе к решению этой проблемы и можно ли это сделать как-то "изящнее", например при помощи хранения массива товаров в ячейке паллеты?

Comment: Массивы в реляционных БД это зло. Тот подход, что вы привели как раз и используется в таких базах.

Comment: @Mike спасибо, так и сделал.